# Terraform + Helm: Set array of environment variables in Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I'm stuck trying to set an array of helm properties from my Terraform code. More precisely, I've got the following value I'd like to set through terraform

[image: Helm variable to set]

My guess is that I need to do something like this:

```
set {
  name = "env"
  value = "{ATL_PROXY_NAME: jira.example.com,ATL_PROXY_PORT: 443,ATL_TOMCAT_SCHEME: https}"
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvVar: got "string", expected "map"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The value type of `env` should be an array of objects with the keys (`name`, `value`), with terraform we can define the array elements and set their values one by one:

1. set the value for the key `name` for the element at index x
2. set the value for the key `value` for the element at index x

```
set {
  name  = "env[0].name"
  value = "ATL_PROXY_NAME"
}
set {
  name  = "env[0].value"
  value = "jira.example.com"
}
set {
  name  = "env[1].name"
  value = "ATL_PROXY_PORT"
}
set {
  name  = "env[1].value"
  value = "443"
}
set {
  name  = "env[2].name"
  value = "ATL_TOMCAT_SCHEME"
}
set {
  name  = "env[2].value"
  value = "https"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Cross-referencing the [helm_release resource documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release) with Helm behavior and Kubernetes manifest syntax, we would expect to construct a `set` block in the resource with `map` type within Terraform (as the Kubernetes error message confirms).

The syntax can be fixed like the following:

```
set {
  name  = "env"
  value = {"ATL_PROXY_NAME" = "jira.example.com", "ATL_PROXY_PORT" = 443, "ATL_TOMCAT_SCHEME" = "https"}
}
```

and then the Terraform `map` type will be passed through Helm inputs as the value for the `env` key within the Kubernetes manifest as expected.

Comment: This wont work:  Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required

Comment: Yes providers do update the schema for their resources over time.